# Creating a contact to register usernames

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I have an idea and wish to make a site which will let users register a username on a contract. By calling the contract from their address this will also confirm ownership.

I am wondering is there any examples currently out there for a simple username register?

Answer (score 1):

An example would be:

```
contract Usernames {
    mapping (address => bytes32) public names;
    mapping (bytes32 => address) public owners;

    function associateNameForEver(bytes32 name) {
        if (owners[name] !=0) throw;
        if (names[msg.sender] != 0) throw;
        owners[name] = msg.sender;
        names[msg.sender] = name;
    }
}
```

Once set, it cannot be unset nor changed.

Answer (score -2):

For example, you can see proofofphone.com and his source code https://github.com/blocknotary/proofofphone

Comment: Please post the relevant details on this site.  Answers that are just links are not considered helpful as the linked site may cease to exist.